# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createIcon') Leaflet Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, leaflet

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createIcon') Leaflet Angular

I tried to create an icon function using leaflet so that each case of different type of object will generate a different icon, but it seems like i got this error.

```
map.component.ts:201 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createIcon')
    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createIcon')
    at NewClass._initIcon (leaflet-src.js:7841:29)
    at NewClass._initIcon (leaflet.rotatedMarker.js:23:28)
    at NewClass.onAdd (leaflet-src.js:7748:10)
    at NewClass._layerAdd (leaflet-src.js:6845:10)
    at NewClass.whenReady (leaflet-src.js:4590:15)
    at NewClass.addLayer (leaflet-src.js:6903:10)
    at NewClass.addTo (leaflet-src.js:6783:9)
    at map.component.ts:188:122
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (asyncToGenerator.js:3:1)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:1214:31)
    at zone.js:1121:17
    at zone.js:1137:33
    at asyncGeneratorStep (asyncToGenerator.js:6:1)
    at _throw (asyncToGenerator.js:25:1)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:375:26)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.mjs:24313:33)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:374:52)
    at Zone.run (zone.js:134:43)
    at zone.js:1278:36`
```

here is what i'm working on

```
function cargoIcon(size: number) {
  let icon = new L.Icon({
    iconUrl: '/img/arrow_purple.png',
    iconSize: [size, size / 3],
  });
  return icon;
}

function icoType(data: number) {
  let penanda;
  switch (data) {
    case 2:

      penanda = cargoIcon(32);

      break;
  }
  return penanda;
}
let marker = icoType(ShipType / 10);

navalIcon = L.marker([parseFloat(latitude), parseFloat(longitude)], { icon: marker, rotationAngle: heading - 90 }).addTo(mymap).bindPopup(popup_string); `
```

it suppose to work because i am using the same method as the older website(working on refactoring it) (it's still uses the same version of leaflet).